# Edit Devise failed registration path - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, registration

I've been searching high and low for docs on how to edit the registration path after a failed registration.

I have my signup form on my site index page. On failed registration it redirects to the new_user_registration_path not root where the user was. How do I update this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to achieve this for the sign-up form by using the customfailure app

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if warden_options[:scope] == :user
      new_user_registration_path
    else
      new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end

  def redirect
    store_location!
    flash[:alert] = i18n_message unless flash[:notice]
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

Surely a similar option is possible, that doesn't require overriding the devise registrations controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the devise registrations controller from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

You should be able to add something like this:

```
if resource.save
    #handle this 
else 
    #handle this
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
end
```

Then in your routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

I'm not sure how to do this without overriding the controller

Comment: but you lose the error messages in devise_error_messages - is there any way to preserve these? seems like it should be easy considering the op doesn't even want a redirect - they want the user to stay on the current page!